# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection when updating/deleting

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, rest

`I am currently coding an app that lets user create fishtanks and add different fish to it.
The app uses a many-to-many relation between fish and fishtank (one fishtank has many fish and a fish can be in many fishtanks). I do the same with plants (same code, everything the same), however, when i try to update the quantity/delete a fish from the fishtank the error pops up: Found shared references to a collection. I have tried everything i have found and anything works, hope any of you can help me.

This is the code for the fish entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name= "pez")
public class Pez extends RepresentationModel implements Serializable {

    @JsonView(Views.Pez.class)
    @Id
    @Column(name="nombre_cientifico", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String nombre_cientifico;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="tamano_medio",nullable = true)
    private int tamano_medio;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="volumen_minimo",nullable = true)
    private int volumen_minimo;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="poblacion_minima",nullable = true)
    private int poblacion_minima;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="temperatura_minima",nullable = true)
    private float temperatura_minima;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="temperatura_maxima",nullable = true)
    private float temperatura_maxima;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="ph_minimo",nullable = true)
    private float ph_minimo;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="ph_maximo",nullable = true)
    private float ph_maximo;

    @JsonView(Views.Pez.class)
    @Column(name="imagen",nullable = true, length=3000 )
    private String imagen;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCreado.class)
    @Column(name="origen",nullable = true)
    private String origen;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCompleto.class)
    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modified_by;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCompleto.class)
    @Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false)
    @CreatedBy
    private String created_by;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCompleto.class)
    private boolean revisado;

    @JsonView(Views.PezCompleto.class)
    @Column(name = "modified_at")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime modified_at;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pez")
    Set<PezAcuario> acuariosPez = new HashSet<>();
```

The code for fishtank entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"pecesAcuario", "plantasAcuario"})
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name= "acuario")
public class Acuario extends RepresentationModel<Acuario> implements java.io.Serializable {
    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioLista.class)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioLista.class)
    @Column(name = "nombre_acuario", nullable = false)
    private String nombreAcuario;

    @JsonView(Views.Acuario.class)
    private boolean publico;


    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioLista.class)
    @Column(name="imagen",nullable = true, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String imagen;

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioLista.class)
    @Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false)
    @CreatedBy
    private String creador;

    @JsonView(Views.Acuario.class)
    @Column(name = "modified_at")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime fechaUltimaModificacion;

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "acuario")
    Set<PezAcuario> pecesAcuario = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "acuario")
    Set<PlantaAcuario> plantasAcuario = new HashSet<>();

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "acuario")
    Set<EquipamientoAcuario> equipamientoAcuario = new HashSet<>();
```

the code for the relation

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

public class PezAcuario  implements java.io.Serializable {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pez_id")
    private Pez pez;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "acuario_id")
    private Acuario acuario;


    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    private int cantidad;
    
}
```

the controller in which i add an dupdate the fish to the fishtank:

```
@GetMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Peces")
    public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<?>> getPecesAcuario(@PathVariable Long id, @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser){
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));
        if(acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())) {
            List<PezAcuario> pecesAcuario = acuario.getPecesAcuario().stream().toList();
            for(PezAcuario pezAcuario:pecesAcuario){
                pezAcuario.getPez().add(linkTo(methodOn(PezController.class).listarPez(pezAcuario.getPez().getNombre_cientifico(),null)).withSelfRel());
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(CollectionModel.of(pecesAcuario, añadirLinks(id)));
        }
        else{
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para acceder a este acuario");
        }
    }

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @PostMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Peces")
    public ResponseEntity<Acuario> añadirPez(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody PezAcuarioDto pezAcuarioDto, @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser) {
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));

        if(!acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())){
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para modificar este acuario");
        }


        Pez pez=pezService.findById(pezAcuarioDto.getNombreCientifico()).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el pez"));
        if(pezAcuarioRepository.findOneByAcuarioAndPez(acuario,pez).isPresent())
            throw new ApiRequestException("Ya existe un pez con ese nombre cientifico en el acuario");
        if(pezAcuarioDto.getCantidad()<=0)
            throw new ApiRequestException("La cantidad debe ser mayor que 0");
        PezAcuario pezAcuario = new PezAcuario();
        pezAcuario.setAcuario(acuario);
        pezAcuario.setPez(pez);
        pezAcuario.setCantidad(pezAcuarioDto.getCantidad());
        pezAcuarioRepository.save(pezAcuario);
        //acuario.getPecesAcuario().add(pezAcuario);
        System.out.println("el contenido de pecesacuario es: "+acuario.getPecesAcuario());
        System.out.println("añadiendo el pez: "+pez+" al acuario: "+acuario);
        acuario.add(añadirLinks(id));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(acuario);
    }

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @PutMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Peces/{nombreCientifico}")
    public ResponseEntity<Acuario> modificarPez(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String nombreCientifico,@RequestBody PezAcuarioDto pezAcuarioDto, @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser) {
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));
        System.out.println("el acuario es: "+acuario);

        if(!acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())){
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para modificar este acuario");
        }

        System.out.println("estoy editando porque mi username es: "+loggedUser.getUsername()+" y el creador es: "+acuario.getCreador());

        Pez pez=pezService.findById(nombreCientifico).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el pez"));

        PezAcuario pezAcuario = pezAcuarioRepository.findOneByAcuarioAndPez(acuario,pez).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el pez en el acuario"));
        System.out.println("el pez acuario es: "+pezAcuario);
        if(pezAcuarioDto.getCantidad()<=0)
            throw new ApiRequestException("La cantidad debe ser mayor que 0");

        pezAcuario.setCantidad(pezAcuarioDto.getCantidad());
        System.out.println("la cantidad es: "+pezAcuario.getCantidad());
        pezAcuarioRepository.save(pezAcuario);
        System.out.println("el contenido de pecesacuario es: "+acuario.getPecesAcuario());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(acuario);
    }

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @DeleteMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Peces/{nombreCientifico}")
    public ResponseEntity<Acuario> eliminarPez(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String nombreCientifico, @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser) {
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));

        if(!acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())){
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para modificar este acuario");
        }
        Pez pez=pezService.findById(nombreCientifico).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado la planta"));
        PezAcuario pezAcuario = pezAcuarioRepository.findOneByAcuarioAndPez(acuario,pez).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado la planta en el acuario"));
        pezAcuarioRepository.delete(pezAcuario);
        acuario.add(añadirLinks(id));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(acuario);
    }
```

I am trully desperate, really hope that someone could help me, if you need anything else (more code/translations) im happy to provide it to you. Thank you very much.

If it helps, ill add the code for plant aswell, as that seems not to fail:
The entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name= "planta")
public class Planta extends RepresentationModel implements Serializable {
    @JsonView(Views.Planta.class)
    @Id
    @Column(name="nombre_cientifico", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String nombre_cientifico;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCreada.class)
    private String origen;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCreada.class)
    @Column(name="temperatura_minima",nullable = true)
    private float temperatura_minima;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCreada.class)
    @Column(name="temperatura_maxima",nullable = true)
    private float temperatura_maxima;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCreada.class)
    @Column(name="ph_minimo",nullable = true)
    private float ph_minimo;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCreada.class)
    @Column(name="ph_maximo",nullable = true)
    private float ph_maximo;

    @JsonView(Views.Planta.class)
    @Column(name="imagen",nullable = true, length=3000 )
    private String imagen;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCreada.class)
    private String requerimientos;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCompleta.class)
    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modified_by;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCompleta.class)
    @Column(name = "created_by", updatable = false)
    @CreatedBy
    private String created_by;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCompleta.class)
    private boolean revisado;

    @JsonView(Views.PlantaCompleta.class)
    @Column(name = "modified_at")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime modified_at;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "planta")
    Set<PlantaAcuario> acuariosPlanta = new HashSet<>();
```

The relation:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

public class PlantaAcuario implements java.io.Serializable {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "planta_id")
    private Planta planta;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "acuario_id")
    private Acuario acuario;

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    private int cantidad;
```

the controller methods

```
 @GetMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Plantas")
    public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<?>> getPlantasAcuario(@PathVariable Long id,@AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser){
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));
        if(acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())){
            List<PlantaAcuario> plantasAcuario=acuario.getPlantasAcuario().stream().toList();
            for(PlantaAcuario plantaAcuario:plantasAcuario) {
                plantaAcuario.getPlanta().add(linkTo(methodOn(PlantaController.class).listarPlanta(plantaAcuario.getPlanta().getNombre_cientifico(),null)).withSelfRel());
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(CollectionModel.of(plantasAcuario,añadirLinks(id)));
        }
        else{
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para acceder a este acuario");
        }
    }
    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @PostMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Plantas")
    public ResponseEntity<Acuario> añadirPlanta(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody PlantaAcuarioDto plantaAcuarioDto,@AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser) {
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));

        if(!acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())){
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para modificar este acuario");
        }


        Planta planta=plantaService.findById(plantaAcuarioDto.getNombreCientifico()).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado la planta"));
        if(plantaAcuarioRepository.findOneByAcuarioAndPlanta(acuario,planta).isPresent())
            throw new ApiRequestException("Ya existe una planta con ese nombre cientifico en el acuario");
        if(plantaAcuarioDto.getCantidad()<=0)
            throw new ApiRequestException("La cantidad debe ser mayor que 0");
        PlantaAcuario plantaAcuario = new PlantaAcuario();
        plantaAcuario.setAcuario(acuario);
        plantaAcuario.setPlanta(planta);
        plantaAcuario.setCantidad(plantaAcuarioDto.getCantidad());
        plantaAcuarioRepository.save(plantaAcuario);
        acuario.add(añadirLinks(id));
        acuario.getPlantasAcuario().add(plantaAcuario);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(acuario);
    }

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @PutMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Plantas/{nombreCientifico}")
    public ResponseEntity<Acuario> modificarPlanta(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String nombreCientifico, @RequestBody PlantaAcuarioDto plantaAcuarioDto, @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser) {
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));

        if(!acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())){
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para modificar este acuario");
        }


        Planta planta=plantaService.findById(nombreCientifico).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado la planta"));
        PlantaAcuario plantaAcuario = plantaAcuarioRepository.findOneByAcuarioAndPlanta(acuario,planta).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado la planta en el acuario"));
        if(plantaAcuarioDto.getCantidad()<=0)
            throw new ApiRequestException("La cantidad debe ser mayor que 0");

        plantaAcuario.setCantidad(plantaAcuarioDto.getCantidad());
        plantaAcuarioRepository.save(plantaAcuario);
        acuario.add(añadirLinks(id));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(acuario);
    }

    @JsonView(Views.AcuarioCreado.class)
    @DeleteMapping("/Acuario/{id}/Plantas/{nombreCientifico}")
    public ResponseEntity<Acuario> eliminarPlanta(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String nombreCientifico, @AuthenticationPrincipal User loggedUser) {
        Acuario acuario=acuarioService.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado el acuario"));

        if(!acuario.getCreador().equals(loggedUser.getUsername())){
            throw new ApiRequestException("No tienes permisos para modificar este acuario");
        }


        Planta planta=plantaService.findById(nombreCientifico).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado la planta"));
        PlantaAcuario plantaAcuario = plantaAcuarioRepository.findOneByAcuarioAndPlanta(acuario,planta).orElseThrow(() -> new ApiRequestException("No se ha encontrado la planta en el acuario"));
        plantaAcuarioRepository.delete(plantaAcuario);
        acuario.add(añadirLinks(id));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(acuario);
    }
```

I am unable to find a difference but maybe it helps.

Another thing to add is that doing the same thing (creating 2 fishtanks, 1 fish, adding the fish to both fishtanks and changing the quantity on one fishtank) sometimes fails and sometimes it doesnt, im trully lost here